# Mark a specific data with jqplot

Tags: jquery, canvas, jqplot

I have a jqplot line graph which shows users count by date.

I wish to add a mark line on a specific date that describe when I updated my application so I can see if the application change cause any effect. Any ideas?

[This](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) is an example
Look at the top graph.

**I wish to add vertical line with label on x=3. How can I do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much a hack but I find jqplot very inflexible when you want to do stuff out of the "normal":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5],[]], // leave an empty series at the end
    {
      series: [{ 
        showMarker:true
      },
      { 
        showMarker:false,
          pointLabels: { show:true, location: 'ne' } // do not show marker, but do show point label
      }]
  });
  plot1.series[1].data = [[2,plot1.axes.yaxis.min],[2,plot1.axes.yaxis.max]]; //dynamically add the data for the empty series, we do this so we can get the auto-scaled yaxis min/max
  plot1.redraw(); // redraw the plot with adjusted 2nd series
  $('.jqplot-point-label.jqplot-series-1.jqplot-point-0').html('x=2'); // manually adjust the label on the 2nd series (I could not find a way to do this with the builtin methods)

})​
```

Produces:

[image]

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/1271/).